# Typescript Angular how to pass filter text to directive

Tags: angularjs, filter, typescript, directive

I am trying to create a filter textbox using a directive for reuse but am unsuccessful in passing the filterText. What am I missing here?

TS Directive:

```
export class FilterTextboxDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static CreateDirective: () => any = () => {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "ageneralapp/components/views/filtertextbox.html",
            scope: {
                //showFilterTextbox: "=",
                //placeholderText: "=",
                filterText: "=?"
            },
            controller: "FilterTextboxController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            bindToController: true
        };

        return directive;
    }

    constructor() {
        return FilterTextboxDirective.CreateDirective();
    }
}
getModule().directive("filtertextbox", FilterTextboxDirective.CreateDirective);
```

}

TS Controller:

module ANamespace.Components.Controllers {
    "use strict";

```
export class FilterTextboxController {
    static controllerName: string = "FilterTextboxController";
    displayFilterTextbox: boolean = false;
    placeholderText: string = "";
    filterText: string="";

    activate = (): void => {
        this.placeholderText = this["placeholderText"];
        this.filterText = this["filterText"];
    };

    showFilterTextbox = (): void => {
        this.displayFilterTextbox = true;
    };

    hideFilterTextbox = (): void => {
        this.displayFilterTextbox = false;

    };


    constructor() {
        this.activate();
    }
}
getModule().controller(FilterTextboxController.controllerName, FilterTextboxController);
```

}

HTML for FilterTextbox:

```
        <div>
            <span>
                <i ng-click="vm.showFilterTextbox()" class="search"></i>
                <span ng-show="vm.displayFilterTextbox">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{{vm.placeholderText}}" ng-model="filterText" />
                    <i ng-click="vm.hideFilterTextbox()" class="exit"></i>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

HTML Index:

```
        <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns">
            <filtertextbox filterText="filterText"></filtertextbox>
        </div>
       <div ng-repeat="something in vm.primaryData | filter:filterText">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns" valign="top">
                    <span><i class="svg icon large icon-customer"></i></span>
                    <strong><span data-ng-bind="something.fullName"></span></strong>
                </div>
                <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns" valign="top">
                    <span data-ng-bind="something.zip"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This doesn't work. Does anybody see what I a missing?  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have :

```
<filtertextbox filterText="filterText"></filtertextbox>
```

please move `filterText` into the `vm` e.g.:

```
<filtertextbox filterText="vm.filterText"></filtertextbox>
```

Otherwise it can easily get disconnected e.g. with an ng-repeat.

## More

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E

Comment: If you have the opportunity give React+TSX a go. You can poke around the source code for http://alm.tools/ to get a feel